# Dividing by bigger value of substraction

Tags: python, numpy, calculation

I have two matrices of shape `(43, 25520)`, they are called `m1` and `m2`.

```
if m1 <= m2:
    distance = (m1 - m2) / m2
else:
    distance = (m1 - m2) / m1
```

So for each index `i`, I want to subtract `m2[i]` from `m1[i]`, and divide by the larger value of those two.

My error message is

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How do I fix the error and accomplish what I want.

Comment: how do you mean *"subtract m2 from m1"*? How does one subtract matrices of uneven size?

Comment: I think it is asking how can you compare two arrays (matrices), and it is suggesting you to use .any or .all. Moreover, when you solve this, I'm not sure about the definition of matrix division.

Comment: @fernand0 dividing two matrices is possible, but it another algorithm.

Comment: So in the end I want a new matrix also of size (43, 25520) that has at (1,1) the value of m1(1,1) - m2(1,1) / the larger value.. either m1(1,1) or m2(1,1) ... and so on for all (43,25520) values

Comment: But you are using the whole matrix and not the particular (1,1) element (i,j). It does not work in this way, at least, for the <= operator. This is the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`np.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) returns the element-wise maximum of two matrices:

```
(m1 - m2) / np.maximum(m1, m2)
```

If you want only positive values less than one, use [`np.absolute`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html):

```
np.absolute((m1 - m2) / np.maximum(m1, m2))
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
(np.maximum(m1, m2) - np.minimum(m1, m2)) / np.maximum(m1, m2))
```

The reason that you get the error is that the expression `m1 >= m2` is a boolean mask of the same size as both arrays. You can't convert a large array of booleans into a single boolean, and even if you could, the expressions in the `if` and `else` operate on entire arrays. You need to vectorize the condition, which I've shown you how to do.